# Ignore Sibling-Modules During Maven Javadoc/Site Compilation

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-site-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a Maven-managed project which contains a few modules, one of which is the actual library of interest. The other modules are just add-ons or examples that build off of the library. I'm looking to generate the Maven site for this library and have it automatically deployed (as a standalone site and not as part of a multi-module site) but I am having trouble with the Javadoc plugin.

When executing the `javadoc:javadoc` goal, the javadoc plugin is attempting to access the `jar` for the other modules causing a failure.

I have [created a simple example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/stackoverflow_question) which demonstrates this phenomenon. Make sure you run the `clean` goal before any others so that the flaw be shown. Though executing the packaging first would solve this error, this cannot be done because the use case occurs during the Maven-managed release process which starts from a clean state.

Is there a way for me to disable this functionality in the javadoc plugin so I only get the documetation for the library module?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options depending on your preference.  Both include using profiles.  If you want the default build to create the javadocs for your library of interest.  Make the other modules use a property inside of the default profile in order to skip the javadocs.

If you are okay with passing in a profile, just have the javadocs only run in the profile.